# How to make a regular expression in preg_match_all "and"

Tags: php, regex, expression, preg-match-all

How to make a regular expression in preg_match_all "and"?

```
The mouse to nibble the cork from the bottle russia king.

$n = preg_match_all("/cork&bottle/i", mb_strtolower($y['foo'], 'UTF-8'), $matches);
```

`/cork&bottle/i`  Does not work

Comment: Does the evaluation need to occur in the specified order, or is it OK to occur in any order?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I'd use:

```
$string = 'The mouse to nibble the cork from the bottle russia king.';
preg_match_all("/^(?=.*(cork))(?=.*(bottle))/i", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => cork
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => bottle
        )

)
```

**Explanation:**

```
/                   : regex delimiter
    ^               : begining of line
    (?=             : start lookahead
        .*          : 0 or more any character
        (\bcork\b)  : capture group #1 that contains "cork" with word boundaries
    )               : end of look ahead
    (?=             : start lookahead
        .*          : 0 or more any character
        (\bottle\b) : capture group #2 that contains "bottle" with word boundaries
    )               : end of look ahead
/i                  : regex delimiter, case insensitive
```